# Modal não funciona após Load div

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Bom, meu problema é, tenho uma função num arquivo externo

```
function lista_contas(id) {
    var url = 'lista_dados.php';
    var method = 'POST';
    var params = 'id='+id;
    params += '&select_ano='+document.getElementById('select_ano').value;
    var container_id = 'list_container' ;
    var loading_text = '<div class="span12 responsive" data-tablet="span12 fix-offset" data-desktop="span12" style="margin:0 auto"><img src="img/load.gif"></div>' ;
    // call ajax function
    ajax (url, method, params, container_id, loading_text) ;
}
```

Chamo ela num onclick, dentro da div list_container são carregados umas tables, que possuem links para modais, esses modais não estão abrindo após o onclick.
Chamo os modais assim:

```
$('#finaliza_conta').on('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
});

$('.conta_finaliza').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    document.getElementById('id_conta').value =  id;
    $('#finaliza_conta').data('id', id).modal('show');
});
```

Obs: Modais bootstrap 2.3.2

Será que é porque a página lista_dados.php, não está carregando os arquivos referentes aos modais?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar:

```
$('#list_container').on('click', '.conta_finaliza', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   document.getElementById('id_conta').value =  id;
   $('#finaliza_conta').data('id', id).modal('show');
});
```

Se entendi bem os elementos com classe `.conta_finaliza` são criados dinamicamente. Para poder definir eventos neles é necessário associar o evento a partir de um elemento pai.